# spring boot get checkbox value

Tags: javascript, java, spring, thymeleaf

class question:

```
class question{
          private String questionContent;
          private String questionId;
          private List<String> options;
     }
```

my jsonData :

```
[{'questionContent': 'content1', 'options': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], 'questionId': '001'},
 {'questionContent': 'content2', 'options': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']}, 'questionId': '002']
```

and i use fastjson to create a list

```
List<Question> questionList = JSON.parseArray(jsonData, Question.class);
```

use thymeleaf to create checkbox:

```
<form>
<div th:each="question : ${questionList}">
    <div>
        <label th:text="${question.questionContent}"></label>
    </div>
    <div th:each="question2 : ${question.Options}">
        <input class="options" th:name="${question.questionId}"
         type="checkbox" th:value="${question2}">
    </div>
</div>
</form>
```

spring boot how to get the value of checkbox？How to implement the controller？
or ajax post data?

Answer (score 0):

You could use Jquery to submit the data manually as json to a REST POST endpoint at the backend.
You could follow any method as you like.In this case what i have done is trigger the jquery form submit when the form is submitted and use ajax to make a POST request to the rest controller.Here,i assumed that a particular group of checkbox will only have on checkbox selected.You will have to modify it otherwise.

**Using Jquery :**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$( "form" ).submit(function() {
  event.preventDefault();

 var questions;
 questions = {}; 
 $.each($("input[type='checkbox']:checked"),function(){
   var questionName,questionValue;
   questionValue = $(this).val();
   questionName = $(this).attr('name')
   questions[questionName] = questionValue;
 });

$.ajax({
type : 'POST',
contentType : "application/json;charset=utf-8",
url : '/endpoint/questions/save',
data : JSON.stringify(questions),
dataType : 'json',              
success : function(data) {

        }
    });
});
});
```

And a rest endpoint like :

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/endpoint/questions")
public class QuestionsController {

    @Autowired
    private QuestionsService service;

    @PostMapping
    @RequestMappint("/save")
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
    public Long create(@RequestBody Questions resource) {
        Preconditions.checkNotNull(resource);
        return service.create(resource);
    }
}
```